# Importing various CSV-files with dynamic header names and dynamic amount of columns

Tags: excel, vba, csv, dynamic

Here is what I need to do (Office365):
Every morning a user downloads a variable number of road traffic reports in CSV-format; all the files will go into the same folder. The macro I'm creating can be copied into the same folder, and will automatically import all the CSVs into a workbook; one worksheet for each CSV. This is all done, but now is when I'm running into problems.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgokU.jpg)

**I don't know how many columns each CSV will have (this depends on the number of lanes of traffic), and I don't know the names of the headers of each lane.** By removing column=xx from File.Contents in the PowerQuery I did manage to get the table to adapt in size (number of columns), but it is costing to change columns with unknown headers to Int64.Type

**The first header (Column1) is "date" - I set it to datetime. The second header (Column2) is "period" - I set it to text. All the following columns shall be set to Int64.Type (the final column is "totalVolume").**
The stuff I have tried:1) I tried removing the remaining headers altogether from the query, but the cells turn into a general/text type that I cannot fix later, 2) I have played with if / else, but without success. 3) I have tried Source instead of #Promoted Header; it's less elegant, but it allows me to replace the unknown headers with Column3, Column4, etc... - the problem here is that I need to know the amount of columns to avoid errors, 4) finally I tried calling functions, but I fall short.

**The code below works, apart from setting all the columns with unknown headers to Int64.Type**

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=QueryName, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & File2Find & """),[Delimiter="","", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & _
        "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" =Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""date"", type datetime}, {""period"", type text}, {""totalVolume"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array("OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""" & QueryName & """;Extended Properties="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
     .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array( _
        SelectQuery)
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
       .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = QueryName
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
   End With
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(QueryName, 29)
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries(ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count).Delete


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chEZD.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried instead using `workbooks.open(pathToCSVFile)` and copying the opened sheet to your workbook?  If the default formatting etc is OK then that should be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the pattern of the column types, you can just generate them dynamically.

For what you state, the **M Code** might look like:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\New Text Document.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

/*set datatypes dynamically with
   first column as datetime
   2nd column as text
   subsequent columns as Int64.Type*/

colNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), //or however you've named the previous step
col1Type = List.Transform({List.First(colNames)},each {_,DateTime.Type}),
col2Type = List.Transform(List.Range(colNames,1,1), each{_, Text.Type}),
remColsType = List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(colNames,2), each{_,Int64.Type}),

colTypes = List.Combine({col1Type,col2Type,remColsType}),

    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",colTypes)

in
    typeIt
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks Ron - that took a bit of tweaking, but I got it to work (based on your response, and with some assistance).

Here is the final version that worked:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=QueryName, Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & File2Find & """),[Delimiter="","",Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    headers = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(headers)," _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    col1Type = List.Transform({List.First(colNames)},each {_,DateTime.Type})," _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    col2Type = List.Transform(List.Range(colNames,1,1), each{_, Text.Type})," _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    remColsType = List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(colNames,2), each{_,Int64.Type})," _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    colTypes = List.Combine({col1Type,col2Type,remColsType})," _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(headers,colTypes) in typeIt"
```